# Rest Service Post parameters

Tags: json, http, rest, post, service

I have rest services that i will be posting data to. Is it better to post data using http form elements in the post data or is it better to post all the data in one json string and then parse the string at the server side. Any reason to go one way vs the other?

Thanks in advance. I am trying to make sure architecturally we code this the best way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the first solution because it is more close to the RESTful architecture. In addition, this solution is a standard, so you will don't need to do extra things to encode / decode the POST parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your data.
If your data is quite flat with a one to one correspondence between keys and simple values then the form style submission is probably most appropriate. If you have more complex nested data or an array of some kind I would roll with the json approach. I don't think either option is more or less RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

Form elements are the way to go. If you use json in your post, then you need to communicate the structure to the clients. This is usually done out-of-band (I've never seen it done in-band, but I might be wrong), which creates a coupling between the client and the server.

When you use a form, the in-band form communicates to the client what the post data should be. When the data requirements change, the form is changed and the client can (possibly) adjust accordingly.

For instance, just say you've defined the following nouns in your media-type: `email`, `password`, `first-name`, `last-name`, `date-of-birth` etc and you have a user creation form that requires `email` and `password`, with the other user optionally data populated later on (via another form). Later it's decided that you want users to provide their name when the account is created, so you update the form so that is requires `email`, `password`, `first-name` and `last-name`. Since the clients are already familiar with these nouns (and know what data belongs in each), well written clients will be compatible with the updated form. If it was just json data being posted, the clients would not work as they would have no idea the required json data had changed (unless you change the media-type, in which case you'll break them anyway).

Now this approach only works for nouns that have been defined in your media-type. If you are adding a new noun, then you can either only ever make it optional (existing clients will still work, new clients can take advantage of the new noun) or if you need to make it required, then you need to create a new media-type, which only new (or updated) clients will be able to use.